# Looking up timezone from region / coordinates

Tags: timezone, nodatime

I would like to look up a timezone based on an ISO region code or coordinates.

I have a collection of data points with coordinates, county and region codes, eg:

33.942501,-118.407997,"US","US-CA"

I want to find the IANA timezone identifier, eg. `America/Los_Angeles`, based on the above info.

Is it possible to do that with `NodaTime`? I cannot see a way to look up `DateTimeZone` or timezone identifier from a region code or location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GeoTimeZone](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeoTimeZone/) NuGet package can provide a lookup by lat/long to IANA ID, and then you can use `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[id]` to get the `DateTimeZone` from that. See the [project home page](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/GeoTimeZone) for more details.

Within Noda Time itself, you can use `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default` (or one that you've loaded) and then the `ZoneLocations` or `Zone1970Locations` properties to find zones for specific ISO-3166 countries... but they doesn't go below the "country" level (although they do have exemplar lat/long values). They're based on [zone.tab](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/zone.tab) and [zone1970.tab](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/zone1970.tab) - so any information not in that file isn't present in Noda Time either.

It sounds like GeoTimeZone is probably your best option here.